# Who's calling with Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to write a logger role (with Log::Dispatchouli, but that shouldn't matter) that tells me from which package, sub, line etc. I have been issuing log messages. Naturally, I tried with caller, but stack is full of Moose classes and the number of frames changes in different situations. Is there a way to get similar info using MOP or Moose? Or perhaps there is a module to filter caller stack? Thanks a lot!

```
package logger

sub log {...}

#some_package
log "bla"

#intended output
some_package l.12 bla
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Carp's longmess function](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html) to produce a stack trace.  It's poorly documented, but its been there for a long time and pretty safe to use.  `cluck` and `confess` are just `warn longmess` and `die longmess` respectively.

The advantage of using `longmess()` is [Carp has several global variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html#GLOBAL-VARIABLES) to control what it considers to be "internal".  This effectively stops them from appearing in stack traces.  The two you care about are `@CARP_NOT` and `%Carp::Internal`.  Which you should use depends on how you're logging.

`@CARP_NOT` affects only stack traces originating from the package that set `@CARP_NOT`.  So you could write your logger something like this:

```
package MyLogger;

use Carp;
our @CARP_NOT = qw(MyLogger Moose More::Moose::Stuff);

sub trace {
    # For example...
    warn Carp::longmess("Trace message");
}
```

`MyLogger::trace()` should report a trace message but ignore itself, Moose and whatever else you put into `@CARP_NOT`.

`%Carp::Internal` is sort of a global version of this.  If you can't centralize where the Carp functions are called into a logging package, you can add packages to `%Carp::Internal`.  Unfortunately this is global and has all the problems of setting a global variable.  If you're going to mess with it, be sure to add packages to it like `$Carp::Internal{"Some::Module"}++`.  Do not overwrite it like `%Carp::Internal = ("Some::Module" => 1)`.